# What is the correct way of reusing a function in for loop without resetting variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I came across this problem when I was trying to optimize my code. I am trying to use a function in my code (seems like I have to repeat code 2 times to make it work, because I am not getting the result I want):

```js
let tmpCont = undefined;
let tmpPrice = undefined;

let evaluate = undefined;
let evaluate2 = undefined;

let cont = 0;
let tmp = true;

let cont2 = 30;
let tmp2 = false;

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  evaluate = analize(cont, tmp);
  console.log(evaluate + "test");

  evaluate2 = analize(cont2, tmp2);
  console.log(evaluate2);
}

function analize(tmpCont, tmpPrice) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tmpCont++;
  }
  return [tmpCont, tmpPrice];
}
```

Result I am getting (what I dont want):

```
10,truetest
[ 30, false ]
10,truetest
[ 30, false ]
10,truetest
[ 30, false ]
10,truetest
[ 30, false ]
10,truetest
[ 30, false ]
10,truetest
[ 30, false ]
10,truetest
[ 30, false ]
10,truetest
[ 30, false ]
10,truetest
[ 30, false ]
10,truetest
[ 30, false ]
```

My question is: Am I doing something wrong? I know why I am getting the result I dont want and I think something is missing **BUT do i have to repeat code to get the result below?**

Result I want:

```
10,truetest
[ 40, false ]
20,truetest
[ 50, false ]
30,truetest
[ 60, false ]
40,truetest
[ 70, false ]
50,truetest
[ 80, false ]
60,truetest
[ 90, false ]
70,truetest
[ 100, false ]
80,truetest
[ 110, false ]
90,truetest
[ 120, false ]
100,truetest
[ 130, false ]
```

Comment: What is `tmpPrecio`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I corrected the code.

Comment: @George I tried that and did it in the code but I get the same thing (I edited that in my code).

Comment: You are passing in cont and cont2 which are 0 and 30 into analize, and then you are changing the tmpCont by += 10. This does not change the original variable value. Instead you can change cont and cont2.

Comment: If it can be thought of, it can be coded. The problem statement is not very clear.

Comment: When you call "evaluate = analize(cont, tmp);" cont values gets inject in the tmpCont argument and therefore the original cont is not changed. it's not being reset. It's not being changed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript all variables passed into a function are [passed by value](http://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/) not by reference.  Changing the value in a function will not change the value of a variable passed.  You have 2 options:

1. Pass an object containing your counts.
2. Assign the returned values.

so to do the first:

```js
let evaluate = undefined;
let evaluate2 = undefined;

const values={cont:0, price:true};
const values2={cont:30, price:false};

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  evaluate = analize(values);
  console.log(evaluate + " test");

  evaluate2 = analize(values2);
  console.log(evaluate2);
}

function analize(tmp) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    tmp.cont++;
  }
  return [tmp.cont, tmp.price];
}
```

or:

```js
let evaluate = undefined;
let evaluate2 = undefined;

let cont = 0;
let tmp = true;

let cont2 = 30;
let tmp2 = false;

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  [cont,tmp] = analize(cont, tmp);
  console.log([cont,tmp] + " test");

  [cont2, tmp2]= analize(cont2, tmp2);
  console.log([cont2, tmp2]);
}

function analize(tmpCont, tmpPrice) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tmpCont++;
  }
  return [tmpCont, tmpPrice];
}
```

Comment: @DaniëlCamps  Not quite.  passing by reference would mean that if you have `function foo(a){a={};}` then calling `var b={c:1}; foo(b)` would change the value of b, which it doesn't.  What you are passing is kind-of a pointer to an object.  You can change the contents, but changing where it points will not modify the variable which you pass in.

Comment: see [here](http://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/) for a more complete answer

Comment: You're right, the value is a reference object. I deleted my previous comment

Answer (score -1):

You could just increment the values at the end of each for loop

```js
let tmpCont = undefined;
let tmpPrice = undefined;

let evaluate = undefined;
let evaluate2 = undefined;

let cont = 0;
let tmp = true;

let cont2 = 30;
let tmp2 = false;

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  evaluate = analize(cont, tmp);
  console.log(evaluate + "test");

  evaluate2 = analize(cont2, tmp2);
  console.log(evaluate2);
  cont += 10 // this
  cont2 += 10 // and this 
}

function analize(tmpCont, tmpPrice) {

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tmpCont++;
  }

  return [tmpCont, tmpPrice];
}
```